# A regex alternative to split?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I convert the following string

```
"str 1<tab>str 2<tab>str 3<tab>str 4..........<tab>str n<tab and some whitespace>"
```

to

```
"*str 1*<tab>*str 2*<tab>*str 3*<tab>*str 4*..........<tab>*str n*<tab and some whitespace>"
```

where str could be "Stack - overflow" or "Super : User" i.e words containing some space and special characters.

I know we can use split and work this out. Is there a way using only =~ s///.. ?

Thanks in advance !

Trinity

Comment: Is `<tab>` stands for tabulation or is it literaly `<tab>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str =~ s/([^\t]+)/*$1*/g;  # Wrap all non-tab groups with '*'s
```

To deal with the 'special characters', simply add it to the list of *unwanted* items:

```
$str =~ s/([^\t:-]+)/*$1*/g;
```

Comment: That, or replace all tabs with "*\t*"

Comment: @RichardHuxton : Not quite. It would miss putting an asterisk at the beginning and end of the string.